# Can't control arduino analog read via Visual Studio GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, arduino

I'm trying to make GUI for my arduino analogread. The GUI display graph and text line of the value that arduino read. I'm using zedgraph for graphing.
I need to write "on" in the serial monitor window of arduino to start the readings. it runs well. But when I try to control via GUI I made with C# Visual
Studio, the reading won't start. it says "Access to the port 'COM3' is denied".

Here's my arduino code:

```
void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0)
 {
     input += (char) Serial.read(); // Read in one char at a time
     delay(5);
 } if (input == "on")
 {
     myservo.write(0);
  ---analog reading and Serial.println arduino---
 } if (input == "off")
 {
     myservo.write(115);
 }
 }
```

And this is my visual studio code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Globalization;

namespace concentrationMeasurement
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort myport;
    private DateTime datetime;
    private string in_data;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 115200;
        myport.PortName = port_name.Text;
        myport.Parity = Parity.None;
        myport.DataBits = 8;
        myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myport.DataReceived += myport_DataReceived;
        try
        {
            myport.Open();
           myport.WriteLine("on");
            data_tb.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
        }
    }

    private void myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        in_data = myport.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
    }

    private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        string time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;
        data_tb.AppendText(time + "\t\t" + in_data + "\n");
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myport.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try{
        string pathfile = @"C:\Users\ajis.aprl\Documents\TA bgt\data_GUI\";
        string filename = "concentration.txt";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathfile + filename, data_tb.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved to "+pathfile,"Save File");
        }
        catch (Exception ex3){
            MessageBox.Show(ex3.Message, "Error");
        }
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plotGraph();
        SetSize();
    }

   private void plotGraph()
    {
       GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        myPane.Title.Text = "Concentration Growth";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "time";
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "concentration";
    }

}
}
```

So I got 2 problem here:

1. As I said, I can't run my analog reading via GUI, it says "Access to the port 'COM3' is denied".
2. in myPane.Title.Text, myPane.XAxis.Title.Tex, and myPane.YAxis.Title.Text, there's error in "Text" it says:

"Error 3 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I googled everywhere but I can't find the answer. Please if anyone know what I'm missing. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code/logic? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have something else using the COM port? For example, the Arduino serial monitor?

Comment: i have closed arduino serial monitor before running the VS. there's nothing connected to my COM too

Comment: @uint128_t i have closed arduino serial monitor before running the VS. there's nothing connected to my COM too